# To select a string enclosed in double quotes from the record in csv file separated by delimitter comma

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having a CSV file with below sample row. Each filed is separated by `,` separator. But you can see inside the double quotes there is a comma.

How to fetch the `,` separated string enclosed in double quotes? It should not be considered as delimiter.

Please help in Oracle PL/SQL language code.

```
12791750024,"ROSETTE","ROLLIN","6,RUE DE MALLEVILLE","95880ENGHIEN LES BAINS",35000,53.4400000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL? To read a CSV file? If I may, I'd suggest another option - **SQL*Loader**. It offers two options that solve your problem; these are

```
fields terminated by ',' 
optionally enclosed by '"'
```

---

I created test table which is supposed to accept data you have in the CSV file:

```
SQL> desc dq;
 Name                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- ----------------
 ID                               NUMBER
 NAME_1                           VARCHAR2(10)
 NAME_2                           VARCHAR2(10)
 ADDR1                            VARCHAR2(25)
 ADDR2                            VARCHAR2(25)
 NUM1                             NUMBER
 NUM2                             NUMBER

SQL>
```

Control file (as `infile`, you'd use path to your CSV file, e.g. `infile 'c:\temp\myfile.csv'`). For simplicity, I included sample data into `begindata` section.

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table dq
fields terminated by ',' 
optionally enclosed by '"' 
trailing nullcols
( 
id,
name_1,
name_2,
addr1,
addr2,
num1,
num2 decimal external "replace(:num2, '.', ',')"
)

begindata
12791750024,"ROSETTE","ROLLIN","6,RUE DE MALLEVILLE","95880ENGHIEN LES BAINS",35000,53.4400000000000000000000
```

Loading session:

```
c:\Temp>sqlldr scott/tiger control=test17.ctl log=test17.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sri Tra 8 09:03:01 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1

c:\Temp>
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From dq;

          ID NAME_1     NAME_2     ADDR1                     ADDR2                           NUM1       NUM2
------------ ---------- ---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
 12791750024 ROSETTE    ROLLIN     6,RUE DE MALLEVILLE       95880ENGHIEN LES BAINS         35000      53,44

SQL>
```

Here you go; everything is in its place.